# Faster grpstats on large dataset

Tags: matlab, grouping

I have a large Matlab dataset (1,924,014 by 5; ~73.4 MB)

```
Date          id            a           b           c
...
733234        1467          1.2656      1.2718      51.16    
733235        1467          1.2732      1.2794      51.16    
733236        1467          1.2781      1.2844       51.5    
733236        1467            1.26         NaN        NaN    
733237        1467          1.3084         NaN        NaN    
733237        1467          1.3205         NaN        NaN    
733238        1467          1.3125      1.3188      53.85    
733238        1467             1.3         NaN        NaN    
...
```

`Date` is the date in `datenum` form.
I need to average (ignoring `NaN`s) the last three columns for unique `Date`+`id` pairs, as sometimes there is more than one row for a given Date+id pair.

The output I want is

```
Date          id            mean_a      mean_b      mean_c
...
735234        1467          1.2656      1.2718      51.16    
735235        1467          1.2732      1.2794      51.16    
735236        1467          1.2691      1.2844       51.5    
735237        1467          1.3144         NaN        NaN    
735238        1467          1.3062      1.3188      53.85    
...
```

I expected to be able to use

```
grpstats(myDataset, {'Date', 'id'}, 'mean')
```

But it is prohibitively slow. I expect this task could be completed in under 60 seconds.  I think `grpstats` is adding a GroupCount column and adding names to each of the observations, things I don't need.

How can I do this quickly? I am open to ideas whether or not they use `grpstats`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by Date and id with `unique(...,'rows')`, then produce accumulation `subs` for multiple columns with `meshgrid()`, or explicitly with `repmat()`, and finally take a `@nanmean` with `accumarray()`:

```
% Group by date and id
[un,~,pos] = unique(db(:,1:2),'rows');

% Produce row, col subs 
[col,row] = meshgrid(1:3,pos);

% Accumulate 
[un accumarray([row(:), col(:)], reshape(db(:,3:5),[],1),[],@nanmean)]
```

Comment: Very promising! Under 30 seconds on my machine. I really need to learn how to use meshgrid/reshape. Just checking the output now ...

Comment: time the meshgrid, if it takes long enough, e.g. 1/3 of time, I will post the repmat approach to subs creation.

Comment: Data looks good to me! It's fast for my purposes. Just timed it, 99% of the time is spent on the accumulate.